# How to know Android decoder MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(type) is Hardware or software decoder?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediacodec, hardware-acceleration

Is there a way to find out if the decoder that received using MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(type) is a hardware decoder or a software decoder?

Comment: @fadden could you help me figure this out.

Comment: @mstorsjo could you help me figure this out.

Comment: FWIW, you can't @-summon people to a discussion. People only get pinged if they were already taking part in the discussion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no real formal flag for indicating whether a codec is a hardware or software codec. In practice, you can do this, though:

```
MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(type);
if (codec.getName().startsWith("OMX.google.")) {
    // Is a software codec
}
```

(The `MediaCodec.getName()` method is available since API level 18. For lower API levels, you instead need to iterate over the entries in `MediaCodecList` and manually pick the right codec that fits your needs instead.)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it on a Galaxy S6 and the return value when type='video/avc' was 'OMX.Exynos.avc.dec', so I guess it's a hardware decoder?!

Comment: Yes, that's a hardware decoder - Exynos is the name of the SoC that some Samsung devices use.

Comment: Also, in practice, if a hardware decoder exists, it will most probably be returned by `createDecoderByType` instead of a software decoder. That is, if you get a software decoder, that's probably because there is no hardware decoder for the format you requested.

Comment: The problem I am having is that even though the decoder is HW accelerated, the CPU usage is almost 100% on some devices (e.g. Sony Android TV). but I see EXO-player is performing so much better in every case.

Comment: mstorsjo, could you take a look at [a media decoder related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42518843/support-full-swing-android-media-decoder)

Answer (score 3):

Putting it here for anyone it might help. According to code for libstagefright, any codec which starts with `OMX.google.` or `c2.android.` or does not start with (`OMX.` and `c2.`) are all software codecs.

```cpp
//static
bool MediaCodecList::isSoftwareCodec(const AString &componentName) {
    return componentName.startsWithIgnoreCase("OMX.google.")
            || componentName.startsWithIgnoreCase("c2.android.")
            || (!componentName.startsWithIgnoreCase("OMX.")
                    && !componentName.startsWithIgnoreCase("c2."));
}
```

Source:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/MediaCodecList.cpp#320