# support full swing android media decoder?

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, android-mediacodec

When I decode a full swing video using Android `MediaCodec` class, the output is always in studio swing? am I missing a header in the video file?

I know after Android 24, I can use `MediaFormat` class to set `COLOR_RANGE_FULL`?

Any help on this? seems like even setting

```
MediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_RANGE, MediaFormat.COLOR_RANGE_FULL);
```

Also doesn't help on android 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I talked to engineers from Android team at Google, and they mentioned this part of the code should be implemented by OEMs(like Samsung and Qualcomm). and indeed when I reached out to engineers at Qualcomm they confirmed that this is not implemented on their side. I don't have any ETA, but seems like they have started working on this case.